# get mail as a file in outlook angular plugin to send it to server

Tags: outlook, exchangewebservices, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins, outlook-restapi

I am working on a Angular plugin for outlook, we have a functionality to create a opinion based on the mail. for this we need to add the mail itself as a attachment to the form(A form for opinion creation) while creating the opinion and posting to our server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use EWS ([makeEwsRequestAsync API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.mailbox?view=outlook-js-1.5#makeewsrequestasync-data--callback--usercontext-)) with the [GetItem operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/getitem-operation), or use [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/use-rest-api) to obtain the item from the server. This will give you all the properties of the item. You can send this information to your backend and use it as needed. If that doesn't satisfy your needs, then please add a feature request to our [UserVoice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Feature requests on our [UserVoice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins) are considered, when we go through our planning process.